# Drupal JQuery.UI draggable event

Tags: jquery-ui, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm trying to find my way into drupal 7 and learning all the required tech at the same time.

I'd like to display drupal content (say articles) like Post-It and let the user to move them over the web page. The goal is then to save positions and be able to retrieve them (out of scope for this question).

Therefore I planned to use JQuery UI draggable function to act on my specific content-type.

Clicking on the content-type and firing an alert message form JS is working fine (i.e. on node-7 it's OK)....but changing the alert() function to $('#node-5').draggable(); does not work.

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#node-7').click(function(){
        alert("Hello world node-7!");
        });

    $('#node-5').click(function(){
        $('#node-5').draggable();
        });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

What should I do to make this draggable ? Should I define a handler ?(http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/draggable/#event-drag)?

I see many examples around but they are used in drupal modules through behaviours and none are as basics as this need is.
How to make it simple ?

Thanks for your time,
O

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. The code posted here is perfectly okay. What do you mean with, *does not work*?: Does the element not become draggable? Does the element become draggable but not start dragging when you click on it again? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Hi, thx for your reply. When I click on the block nothing happens. I can not move the object. I expected to be able to - at least - be able to move the article displayed. Not being yet able to drop it somewhere but at least to grip and move it. i also do not see any error. Should I check somewhere in particular ?

Comment: Does someone have a magic idea ?